# ActionBarSherlock : Display a transparent margin activity with actionbar above an other one

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the last version of AndroidBarSherlock (4.3.1).

On smartphone, I have an activity (X) and I display an other fullscreen activity (Y) above with my ABS.

When I'm on the tablet, X calls Y. Y needs to be display above X. But X shall not be fullscreen but only be displayed like a dialog box on the center of the screen with the ABS.

Dialog sherlock theme doesn't exists anymore. What is the best solution to do it ? Is it possible to display a SherlockActivity only on the center of the screen with transparent margin ?

Thanks

Comment: use activity as dialog or use fragment dialog...

Comment: I use my activity like dialog. The problem is with ABS. The action bar work only for all the screen and not only for the dialog. So my action bar is on the top of the screen and not with my center dialog. The dialog theme doesn't exist anymore.